# Unable to access dictionary within multiple nested dictionaries because of tuple error

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, tuples

I have a dataframe called output which looks like -

```
output
Out[48]: 
({'results': [{'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.82,
      'transcript': 'thank you for calling a AA health insurance my name is Dick right the pleasure of speaking with '}],
    'final': True},
   {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.57, 'transcript': 'hi Nick this is '}],
    'final': True},
   {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.78,
      'transcript': 'hi Julie I think we talked earlier we did '}],
    'final': True},
  {'alternatives': [{'confidence': 0.86,
      'transcript': "thing else comes up or you have any questions just don't hesitate to call us okay okay thank you so much yeah you're very welcome you have a great rest your day okay you too bye bye "}],
    'final': True}],
  'result_index': 0},)
```

I am trying to access only the 'transcript' and converting this to a dataframe to a csv. I tried -

```
output.to_csv("script.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-44-85a7c839323b>", line 1, in <module>
    output.to_csv("script.csv")

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I also tried to just access the transcript but I got the same below error-

```
print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-03a8e1a518ee>", line 1, in <module>
    print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How do I escape this error?

Comment: It just means that `output` is not a pandas `DataFrame`, but a mere tuple. And as is it a tuple you should use: `print(output[0]['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])`

Comment: @SergeBallesta But this only gives the first instances transcript. There are multiple 'transcripts' after that like 'transcript': 'hi Julie I think we talked earlier we did ', How do I get just all the transcripts combimed into one dataframe and leave the other verticals such as alternatives, result index out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a pandas DataFrames from a list of dictionaries. Assuming you only need the inner most elements, you can use a comprehension to get it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i for elts in output for alts in elts['results'] for i in alts['alternatives']])
```

You will get the following DataFrame:

```
   confidence                                         transcript
0        0.82  thank you for calling a AA health insurance my...
1        0.57                                   hi Nick this is 
2        0.78         hi Julie I think we talked earlier we did 
3        0.86  thing else comes up or you have any questions ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Output is a single element tuple. Access the single element first

```py
>>> type(output)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> len(output)
1
>>> results = output[0]
>>> type(results)
<type 'dict'>
>>> results['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
'thank you for calling a AA health insurance my name is Dick right the pleasure of speaking with '
```

Comment: But this only gives the first instances transcript. There are multiple 'transcripts' after that like 'transcript': 'hi Julie I think we talked earlier we did ', How do I get just all the transcripts combimed into one dataframe and leave the other verticals such as alternatives, result index out of it